# is there any online ssjson generator for spreadjs?

Tags: javascript, json, spreadsheet, wijmo

i am currently using ubuntu, ubuntu-wine & ms office 7 on wine

i want to convert a xls template -> ssjson for testing spreadjs

i got some sjson file links from wijmo's forum

http://wijmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/t.txt

it sucessfully loaded into spreadjs (i don't know - correct amount of content in it)

anybody knows a solution to convert a xls template to spreadjs ssjson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/spreadjs/exceliosample/

is a better option for ubuntu users

first import a xls file after opening console

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON()));
```

then u get ssjson of that template, copy & save it as x.ssjson

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can load the xls file in the Spread Designer, make the desired changes and then, save it as ssjson file. Later, you can load this ssjson file in SpreadJS. You may refer to this following links for more information:

http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-enterprise/spreadjs/v20133-whats-new/
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadHClientUG/webframe.html#spdesigner.html